# How to Retrieve Last Entered Result and Perform Subtraction after that store into SQLite Android

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite, operation

I am creating a STOCK IN System. 
I know how to INSERT a New Record into the Table. 
But now, I require to Perform an ADDITION by Retrieve the Previous Value and ADD with Current Value. 
E.G: 
ROWID | STOCK ID | STOCK AMOUNT | STOCK TOTAL 
01    | A0001 | 20 | 20 
02    | B0002 | 50 | 50 
03    | A0001 | 40 | 60 <<< {Assume this is the new enter value "40", I need to get the "60" when I press STOCKIN into the Database} 
Means 
20 + 40 = 60

**Following is the code:** 
**DBAdapter Class**

```
        public long stockIn(String indate, String proid, String unit, String total, String rack){

            ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
            initialValues.put(KEY_STOCK_IN_DATE, indate);
            initialValues.put(KEY_PRO_CODE, proid);
            initialValues.put(KEY_STOCK_IN_AMT, unit);
            initialValues.put(KEY_STOCK_TOTAL, total);  
            initialValues.put(KEY_STOCK_RACK,rack);     

            return DB.insert(DATABASE_TRANS_TABLE, null, initialValues);

        }
```

**STOCK In Class**

```
public void STOCKIN( ) {

    stockinBttn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            String dateInput, IDInput, unitInput, totalInput, rackInput; 

            dateInput = dateLbl.getText().toString().trim();
             IDInput = proidTxt.getText().toString().trim();
             unitInput = prounitTxt.getText().toString().trim();
             totalInput = prounitTxt.getText().toString().trim();
             rackInput = prorackTxt.getText().toString().trim();

                DB.open();
                long id = DB.stockIn(userInput, dateInput, IDInput, unitInput, rackInput);
                DB.close();


        }});


        }
```

Your guyz suggestion and help is much appreciated.
Regards

Comment: Not exactly sure what you're asking, are you saying you want to do math within a sql call?  One suggestion I have is that you use ints in your java code rather than strings.

Comment: Yes. I need to perform Calculation in the SQLITE. Something like Latest Amount + "Previous Amount" = Total Amount.

Answer (score 0):

Read the [sum](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_aggfunc.html#sumunc) of all previous transactions from the table, and add it to the current amount:

```java
public long stockIn(String indate, String proid, long unit, String rack) {
    long previousTotal = DatabaseUtils.longForQuery(DB,
            "SELECT TOTAL("+KEY_STOCK_TOTAL+")"+
            " FROM "+DATABASE_TRANS_TABLE+
            " WHERE "+KEY_PRO_CODE+" = ?",
            new String[] { proid });
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(KEY_STOCK_IN_DATE, indate);
    cv.put(KEY_PRO_CODE,      proid);
    cv.put(KEY_STOCK_IN_AMT,  unit);
    cv.put(KEY_STOCK_TOTAL,   previousTotal + unit);
    cv.put(KEY_STOCK_RACK,    rack);
    return DB.insert(DATABASE_TRANS_TABLE, null, cv);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. It works great for total up. If I want to get the LAST RECORD and ADD with Current RECORD. How can I apply the (MAX) / DESC LIMIT 1 on it?

Comment: Just use a different query.